# Primefaces treetable selected rows background color

Tags: jsf, primefaces

In treetable when nodes are selected, the rows become grey.

How can I customize primefaces to keep them white when they are selected?

Thank you!

(I got this screenshot from the Primefaces showcase https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/treetable/selection.xhtml)

[image]

Comment: @Makky http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/treeTableCheckbox.jsf;jsessionid=ajhrchz2hjv71n0eb48w238gx Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to over-ride the style class it uses.

Add below code in your xhtml file

```
    <style type="text/css">
/* this is to set proper font size */
   .ui-widget,.ui-widget .ui-widget {
        font-size: 90% !important;
    }

    /* To change background color when selectedis-->*/
    .ui-state-highlight,.ui-widget-content .ui-state-highlight,.ui-widget-header .ui-state-highlight
        {
        background-color: green;
    }
    </style>
```

Try this and it should work.

***How to find out :***

Using firefox browser `right click` on the tree and click `"Inspect Element(Q)"`. It will display the style it is using for. It showed me the above tags so I just override it.

You need to learn little about `CSS`.

Comment: And I have another question about the style of treetable... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17705877/primefaces-treetable-different-background-colors-for-rows-of-different-hierarchy